# Synonymize [windows-applications] to [windows]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[windows-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-applications) are, whatever you might have thought

> Applications which run on the Windows OS

As such, I don't see any reason to have that tag, as it adds nothing over [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)

> Windows is a family of client, server, and mobile operating systems developed by Microsoft. Use this tag only if your question relates to using Windows APIs or Windows-specific behavior. Questions relating to using or troubleshooting Windows are off-topic.

As an aside [windows-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-application) is already synonymized.

Comment: Direct link for voting on the synonym: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows/synonyms

Comment: Why is "car that runs on streets" a synonym of "street"?

Comment: @Braiam: Windows might be compared to street in your analogy (and thus would not be synonymous), but the part which is on-topic and covered by the tag is actually synonymous.

Comment: I would prefer that "windows-applications" are not a tag, if that's the case.

Comment: Just ran across this and had enough tag rep to vote. Synonym approved